# unrecognized selector sent to instance obj c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, crash

2020-02-17 23:12:31.949254+0100 LoyaltyCardsApp[64133:7104122] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[OTPViewController OTPPinInserted:pin:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd00a127730'

```
    @protocol OTPViewControllerDelegate
- (void) OTPAbortedByUser;
- (void) OTPPinInserted: (NSString *) pan pin: (NSString *) pin;


@end

@interface OTPViewController : UIViewController<KeyboardDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) id delegate;

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *confirmButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet InputTextView *insertOTP;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* stringInserted;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet CopyableTextView *result;

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *marginTop;

- (IBAction) clickOnDoneButton:(id)sender;
@end


- (void) pinInserted:(NSString *) pin{

    [self.delegate OTPPinInserted:self.insertOTP.input.text pin:pin];
```

the crash occurs here:

```
    [self.delegate OTPPinInserted:self.insertOTP.input.text pin:pin];
```

other thing, I can't understand why in debug I can't go inside the if ..

```
if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(OTPPinInserted:pin:)]){
    [self.delegate OTPPinInserted:self.insertOTP.input.text pin:pin];
}
```

Comment: i can't find where is the problem..

Comment: Where have you implemented the `OTPPinInserted:pin` method?

Comment: The crash occurs + you cant enter that `if` block, because it is not able to find the `OTPPinInserted:pin` method implemented.

Comment: Please check whether the delegate set properly, or the delegate is not deallocated.

Also check whether the **insertOTP** is not null.

Comment: Always create `delegate` variable with `weak` property, the strong property will lead to memory issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you haven't implemented the `OTPViewController` protocol on the `OTPViewController`.

Or, more specifically, you need to implement this method:

```
- (void) OTPPinInserted: (NSString *) pan pin: (NSString *) pin;
```

(or spell it right if you did implement it. :).

Note that having capital letters prefixed on the method name is a little odd.

I'd stick with `-pinInserted:pin:`.  If you have conflicting method declarations that typically indicates a different design problem.

If you do go the prefix route, then make it lowercase;  `-otpPinInserted:pin:`.